# What does -Convert.ToSingle do?

Tags: c#

I tried to search on Google and Bing this but both return zero results....

What does it mean when you put a hyphen in front of convert?

```
-Convert.ToSingle
```

Comment: a) What happens when you put a *minus sign* in front of any number, and b) What happens when you put a *minus sign* in front of any particular search term in most search engines?

Comment: Search again by removing `-` :)

Comment: @L.B the whole point is the hyphen...

Comment: But, `-` has special meaning to search engines. You use it to trim out results that you don't want to see. If you ever want to see results specifically about a `-` and something else, make sure that the `-` is included inside `""` quotes (although it's quite likely, in such a case, to be trimmed out as noise)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just the `-` operator, applied to the result of calling `Convert.ToSingle(...)`.

So for example when used as a unary operator:

```
double x = 10.52123;
float y = -Convert.ToSingle(x);
```

is equivalent to:

```
double x = 10.52123;
float tmp = Convert.ToSingle(x);
float y = -tmp;
```

Or when used as a binary operator:

```
double x = 10.52123;
float y = 10-Convert.ToSingle(x);
```

is equivalent to:

```
double x = 10.52123;
float tmp = Convert.ToSingle(x);
float y = 10 - tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. On top of it as always

Comment: Is it correct to say that the operator (when applied to `Single` or `Double`) simply sign switches the mantissa?

Comment: @Gusdor: As far as I'm aware, that's correct, yes. But I took `Convert.ToSingle` to just be an example here - I'm trying to provide a more general answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's shorthand for

```
-1 * Convert.ToSingle(...)
```

Since the method returns a `Single` (which is a number, so it's subject to arithmetic operators)

Comment: While that's true for the result of `Convert.ToSingle`, it's not true for all types. Types can overload both the unary and binary `-` operators, but may choose not overload the `*` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The - operator is an unary or a binary operator. The result of a unary - operation on a numeric type is the numeric negation of the operand. For an example

```
  int x = 5;

  float b = -Convert.ToSingle(x);

  Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Here the output should be -5. In the absence of unary operator. The output value should have been just 5

Answer (score 0):

Just think about the *C# syntax*: what means a minus at the right of an assignment? In every language (or almost, don't talk to me about Brainfuck & co), it means **change the sign of the number** which following.
So the operation after this minus has to return a `Number`. Good, that's [what `Convert.ToSingle` does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tosingle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns a `float`.

```
float x = -     Convert.ToSingle(42);
          ^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          ^       function call
        minus operation

// equivalent to:
float x = 0 - Convert.ToSingle(42);
          ^^^
          0 minus the result
```